# What permission allows a listing to be exported to a csv file

Tags: csv

I can't seem to locate the permission that allows a report listing to be downloaded to a csv file. The Actions are present but they don't function. They work on some roles but I haven't been able to narrow down the particular permission that allows this function.

Comment: I have Export as an option in my User Role Editor. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have the same issue.  I can confirm we have Export available in the User Role Editor.